# Firestore Index not working - Responds with same index link which index already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So because the current issue where index links are not generated on client SDKs I have created the following function to get an index link for my query:

```
export const getIndexLink = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const snap = await admin.firestore().collection('WorkoutThreads')
            .where('creatorUid', '==', "cItKL6yLLBaxQ2VYV0at6l9zU243")
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .get()
        console.log(snap.size)
        response.send(snap.size);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        response.send(error.message)
        // Error with index creation link
    }
});
```

I have created the index from the link but the query is still not working, when I call the function again, It return the same index link again. When I open the link, I get a message "This index already exists".

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried deleting existing index and creating new one using the link?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes I just tired, same result

Comment: That's wierd. Can you share screenshot of the index creared? I'd try querying from client sdk as well once. I'll try copying your query as soon as I can but if issue persists then I'd recommend contacting support.